# Django MPTT ошибка с draggable-admin.js

Tags: javascript, django

Установил django-mptt:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey


class Section(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey(
        'self',
        verbose_name='parent',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='children'
    )
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='title', max_length=15, blank=False)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mptt.admin import DraggableMPTTAdmin
from .models import Section


@admin.register(Section)
class SectionAdmin(DraggableMPTTAdmin):
    list_display = ('tree_actions', 'indented_title',)
    list_display_links = ('indented_title',)
```

И всё бы ничего, всё работает, кроме самого перетаскивания в админке. В консоли браузера:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined at draggable-admin.js:14

Судя по всему проблема в том, что mptt свой js подключает до jQuery.init и django.jQuery ещё не существует.

Какой есть менее затратный способ исправить сие недоразумение?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю почему, но проблема оказалась в том, что Django (v. 2.2) подключает свои и чужие js файлы по очереди. Может не самый лучший, но самый менее затратный способ это исправить получилось путём добавления своего js через класс Media.

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Section)
class SectionAdmin(DraggableMPTTAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ('admin/js/fixed.js',)
```

**fixed.js**

```
var django = django || {};
django.jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
```

По сути повторяя джанговский jquery.init.js